# Blender on a macbook pro 2015 Catalina with Intel Iris pro and external Monitor bad performance

Tags: performance, osx, opencl

Blender 2.8.2 performance is very bad with an external Monitor - the basic cube stutters when moving. With the internal Monitor it is ok, with blender 2.97 it is ok. So it seems to have something to to with open CL support. Any suggestions what I can do without buying a Windows PC? I am asking for my Son who loves blender and who loves his Mac.
thanks for help

Markus